# Database Python File

Tags: python, html, database, sqlite, flask

How to create a database file in python?

I’m not too sure how to link python to database using SQLite as the updateDB function isnt working.
This code should work but the update isnt working correctly.

What am I missing?

```py
import sqlite3

class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        self.DBName ='BUYHIRELtd.db'

    def connect(self):
        conn = None
        try: 
            conn = sqlite3.connect(self.DBName)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        return conn

    def queryDB(self, command, params=[]):
        conn = self.connect()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(command, params)
        result = cur.fetchall()
        self.disconnect(conn)
        return result

    def updateDB(self, command, params=[]):
        conn = self.connect()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(command, params)
        result = cur.fetchall()
        self.disconnect(conn)
        return result

    def disconnect(self, conn):
        conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `conn.commit` to save changes to the database.

```
import sqlite3

class Connector:
    dbName = "Database.db"

    def connect(self):
        conn = None
        try:
            conn = sqlite3.connect(self.dbName)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        return conn

    def disconnect(self, conn):
        conn.close()

    def queryDB(self, command, params=[]):
        conn = self.connect()
        cur = conn.cursor()

        cur.execute(command, params)
        result = cur.fetchall()

        self.disconnect(conn)
        return result

    def updateDB(self, command, params=[]):
        conn = self.connect()
        cur = conn.cursor()

        cur.execute(command, params)
        conn.commit()
        result = cur.fetchall()

        self.disconnect(conn)
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you're importing sqlite3 in the top of the database.py file or the commands wont be able to run.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).